# C++ copying array into pointer argument

Tags: c++, arrays

Everyone,

I am writing a class in C++ which calculates points in space. I am designing this class to be independent from the application, so basically what I want -

Initialize object with input parameters -> calculate the values -> retrieve the calculated array

I prefer using C-like array (not the `std::array`). I'm writing the getter function -

```
// The definition of the ctrlpoints array
GLfloat ctrlpoints[4][4][3];

void GlCircle::getControlPoints(GLfloat* controlPoints) {
    std::copy(std::begin(ctrlpoints), std::end(ctrlpoints), std::begin(controlPoints));
}
```

Basically it should copy all values from `ctrlpoints` array to `controlPoints` target array. Of course compiler does not allow me to do just that (it doesn't like the type for `std::begin(controlPoints)`). Maybe someone can suggest an idea how should I return a copy of the array? Maybe the idea can realized in some other way, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I prefer using C-like array (not the `std::array`)."_  Can you give any sensible reasoning for this?

Comment: memcpy(controlPoints, ctrlpoints, sizeof(ctrlpoints));

Comment: I am using `opengl` for drawing the points and it accepts only that kind of array (as far as I know). So it would a more elegant solution, otherwise it requires type convertions..

Comment: @rock-ass: Nope, you can obtain a pointer to the raw data of a `std::array` just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void GlCircle::getControlPoints(GLfloat* controlPoints) {
    std::copy(std::begin(ctrlpoints), std::end(ctrlpoints), std::begin(controlPoints));
}
```

does not work since `std::begin(ctrlpoints)` and `std::end(ctrlpoints)` can be used to iterate over the 2D arrays of a 3D array, it doesn't automatically flatten the 3D array so you can treat it like a 1D array.

You can use three `for` loops to get the data from the member variable to the output argument.

```
void GlCircle::getControlPoints(GLfloat* controlPoints) {
    int index = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
    {
       for ( int j = 0; j < 4; ++j )
       {
          for ( int k = 0; k < 3; ++k )
          {
             controlPoints[index++] = ctrlpoints[i][j][k];
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This simple solution fits my needs and works. Thank you.